# Gráficos do Matplotlib estão se sobrescrevendo

Tags: python, svg, matplotlib, graphics, reportlab

Estou tentando gerar um relatório com vários gráficos gerados pelo [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html#lines-bars-and-markers), porém, percebo que na sequência de gerar os gráficos eles ficam sobrescrevendo outros que já foram criados, segue exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código simples:

```
# Python Imports
import os
import numpy as np


def main():
    if not os.path.exists('teste_graphic'):
        os.makedirs('teste_graphic')

    labels = ['Label 01', 'Label 02', 'Label 03', 'Label 04', 'Label 05']
    values = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

    pie(title='Pie', values=values, labels=labels)
    donut(title='Donut', values=values, labels=labels, hole=.3)
    bar(title='Bar H', values=values, labels=labels, orientation='h')

def bar(title, values, labels, orientation, colors=None):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt_bar
    index = np.arange(len(labels))
    plt_bar.bar(index, values)
    plt_bar.ylabel('Quantidade', fontsize=5)
    plt_bar.xticks(index, labels, fontsize=5, rotation=30)
    plt_bar.title(title)
    plt_bar.savefig('teste_graphic/bar')

def pie(title, values, labels, colors=None, hole=0):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt_pie
    fig, ax = plt_pie.subplots(figsize=(6, 3), subplot_kw=dict(aspect="equal"))
    data = [float(x) for x in values]
    wedges, texts, autotexts = ax.pie(
        data,
        autopct=lambda pct: func(pct, data),
        textprops=dict(color="w")
    )
    ax.legend(wedges, labels,
                # title=title,
                loc="center left",
                bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0, 0.5, 1))
    plt_pie.setp(autotexts, size=8, weight="bold")
    ax.set_title(title)
    # fig.savefig(self._path_image)
    plt_pie.savefig('teste_graphic/pie')

def donut(title, values, labels, colors=None, hole=0):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt_donut
    fig, ax = plt_donut.subplots(figsize=(6, 3), subplot_kw=dict(aspect="equal"))

    wedges, texts = ax.pie(values, wedgeprops=dict(width=0.5), startangle=-40)

    bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="square,pad=0.3", fc="w", ec="k", lw=0.72)
    kw = dict(arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-"),
                bbox=bbox_props, zorder=0, va="center")

    for i, p in enumerate(wedges):
        ang = (p.theta2 - p.theta1) / 2. + p.theta1
        y = np.sin(np.deg2rad(ang))
        x = np.cos(np.deg2rad(ang))
        horizontalalignment = {-1: "right", 1: "left"}[int(np.sign(x))]
        connectionstyle = "angle,angleA=0,angleB={}".format(ang)
        kw["arrowprops"].update({"connectionstyle": connectionstyle})
        ax.annotate(labels[i], xy=(x, y), xytext=(1.35 * np.sign(x), 1.4 * y),
                    horizontalalignment=horizontalalignment, **kw)

    ax.set_title(title)
    plt_donut.savefig('teste_graphic/donut')


def func(pct, allvals):
    absolute = int(pct / 100. * np.sum(allvals))
    return "{:.1f}%\n({:d})".format(pct, absolute)


def autolabel(rects, ax):
    """Attach a text label above each bar in *rects*, displaying its height."""
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.annotate('{}'.format(height),
                    xy=(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height),
                    xytext=(0, 3),  # 3 points vertical offset
                    textcoords="offset points",
                    ha='center', va='bottom')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Como eu consigo gerar esses gráficos de forma independente um do outro? Sem sobrescrever?

Answer (score 0):

Ola!
Fiz apenas a inversão na declaração deles e gerou corretamente, conforme trecho do teu código:

```
    bar(title='Bar H', values=values, labels=labels, orientation='h')
    pie(title='Pie', values=values, labels=labels)
    donut(title='Donut', values=values, labels=labels, hole=.3)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abs!

Comment: Eu já tinha feito isso, mas isso não seria bem uma solução, porque isso aparentemente corrigiu? Entende? Eu fiz um teste usando o **plt.figure(1)** e fui numerando a cada gráfico, aparentemente funcionou, mas ainda vou procurar entender o motivo e posto aqui, a não ser que isso não seja a solução definitiva.